# using color box in a wordpress plugin

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin in which i need to implement colorbox. I have the following code. Plugin works perfectly but the color box is not working. I have copied same colorbox code to an html file and its working. the only problem is in the wordpress plugin. Either i am not importing js and css exactly or any thing other is going wrong. Need help in urgent.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: my plugin
Plugin URI: http://www.xxx.com/
Description: xxx
Author: xxx
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.xxx.com
*/


wp_enqueue_style('colorbox.css', '\wordpress\wp-  
content\plugins\calc_plugin\colorbox.css');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery.js', '\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\calc_plugin\jquery.js',  
array('jquery1'));
wp_enqueue_script('colorbox.js', '\wordpress\wp- 
content\plugins\calc_plugin\colorbox.js', array('jquery2'));

function calc_form_markup() {
$markup = <<<EOT




<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"600", height:"450"});
});
</script>


<div style='display:none' >

<div id='inline_content1' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
<p><strong>This is inline content 1</strong></p>
<image src = "http://wallpaper.goodfon.com/image/240138-1360x768.jpg" width = "175"     
height = " 150">
</div>

</div>

<p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content1">Inline HTML</a></p>

EOT;

return $markup;

}

add_shortcode('calc_form', 'calc_form_markup');


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `wp_enqueue_script` is wrong.

Here are the parameters:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
     $handle
    ,$src
    ,$deps
    ,$ver
    ,$in_footer 
);
```

The `$deps` (dependency) being jQuery, which is included in WordPress already and called using `jquery` NOT `'jquery1'`.

Your JavaScript is wrong, Use a no conflict wrapper in WordPress, which is `jQuery` instead of `$`

`$(document).ready(function()`  Should be `jQuery(document).ready(function()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading the `jQuery` script that is required by Colorbox to function. Just enqueue it before you enqueue `Colorbox.js`.

```
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
```

Comment: I have changed the file with your suggestion and have included the jquery also. Please see the above code now it includes jquery but colorbox still not working